# Ubuntu Live 14.10 Default Password for ubuntu-Desktop-next

Tags: 14.10, password, default

Hi am trying use try ubuntu with live cd,

and i could see there is default username called "Ubuntu-desktop-next"
may i know the password for that.

Comment: You don't need any passwords for the Live CD/DVD. If you truly need to run commands as another user, use `sudo sudo -u [USER] [COMMAND] ...`.

Answer (score 0):

> (the username is "ubuntu-desktop-next" - without the quotes - , and the password is blank which means you must simply hit the enter key)

Source: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/06/ubuntu-desktop-next-unity8-1410-utopic.html

Comment: No its not working. system expecting password

Comment: Can you give me the link to the ISO?